# Text inside <md-icon> tag is not showing

Tags: angular-material

I'm trying to show text which is inside  tag.
text is not appearing on browser. Is it due to default feature of angular material? Do I need to change the HTML structure?

Code is like:

```
<md-icon aria-hidden="true" class="profile ng-scope ng-isolate-scope material-icons">
    <h3 class="ng-binding">ABC</h3>
</md-icon>
```

Comment: Looks okay - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/pbXoOk

Comment: it is not supporting any tag inside <md-icon>.

Comment: Isn't `<h3>` a tag? If not, what do you mean by tag?

Comment: yes <h3> is a tag. when i replace <h3> by any other heading or paragraph still nothing is showing

Comment: Check my CodePen again. It seems fine with other tags.

Answer (score 0):

I find your provided **HTML** is correct. Check if this element is set **display: none** by any class or **display: none** applied on the parent element. If you can give the your page url then I check it for you.